# Tensorflow TPU Error: Shuffle Buffer Filled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have been trying to use tensorflow's TPU's to train a computer vision model but keep getting an error when I commit the notebook in kaggle's environment.

It is really weird because when I run manually run the notebook it works fine and finishes in <20mins, but when I commit the notebook 8/10 times it gets stuck and says the following for 9 hours before the notebooks dies.

[Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/brendanartley/cld-training-on-tpu)

**Stuck with the following message:**

2021-01-08 00:28:59.042056: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:221] Shuffle Buffer Filled.

**What I have tried**

1. lowering the buffer_size
2. Changing order of load function
3. Batch_size tuning

If anyone knows what is happening please let me know!

**Data Pipeline**

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
GCS_PATH = KaggleDatasets().get_gcs_path('cassava-leaf-disease-tfrecords-center-512x512')
BATCH_SIZE = 16 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
IMAGE_SIZE = [512, 512]
TARGET_SIZE = 512
CLASSES = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
EPOCHS = 20

def decode_image(image_data):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data, channels=3) #decoding jpeg-encoded img to uint8 tensor
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0 #cast int val to float so we can normalize it
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE]) #added this back seeing if it does anything
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]) #resizing to proper shape
    return image


def read_tfrecord(example, labeled=True):
    if labeled:
        TFREC_FORMAT = {
            'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 
            'target': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64), 
        }
    else:
        TFREC_FORMAT = {
            'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 
            'image_name': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 
        }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, TFREC_FORMAT)
    image = decode_image(example['image'])
    if labeled:
        label_or_name = tf.cast(example['target'], tf.int32)
    else:
        label_or_name =  example['image_name']
    return image, label_or_name

def load_dataset(filenames, labeled=True, ordered=False):
    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    if not ordered:
        ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.with_options(ignore_order)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: read_tfrecord(x, labeled=labeled), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

def get_training_dataset():
    dataset = load_dataset(TRAINING_FILENAMES, labeled=True)
    dataset = dataset.map(transform, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.repeat() # the training dataset must repeat for several epochs
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048) #set higher than input?
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTOTUNE) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
    return dataset
```

**Fitting the model:**

```
history = model.fit(x=get_training_dataset(),
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                    validation_steps=VALID_STEPS,
                    validation_data=get_validation_dataset(),
                    callbacks = [lr_callback, model_save, my_early_stopper],
                    verbose=1,
                   )
```

Comment: `What I have tried: lowering the buffer_size` Did you try increasing it?

Comment: Yeah I set it to 20000 which is larger than the dataset and that gets stuck as well..

Comment: Can you confirm using a *very* large number, so to verify that the buffer capacity is actually not a problem?

Comment: Yes. When I do set it to VERY large it gets stuck filling the shuffle buffer on commit as well. It reaches the 9hr limit. When I hit run all, it finishes in <20mins..

Comment: If manual run works, then the problem is not in the code of any of the LIbraries. That problem becomes Kaggle-sided. I advise you to post this question on their forum for help. SO would not cover such questions

Comment: Have done so, Thanks @neelg!